# SQL Server login failed for user and all user accounts seem to be disabled

Tags: sql-server, logins

When I tray to login to SQL Server, all users are disabled and fail with error 18470. Even Windows Authentication.

> Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason:
> Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: local machine]

Comment: Anything in the error log file?

Comment: Is that error from SQL Server log or SSMS when you try to login (and you're locked out of the server)?

Comment: @Ronaldo SSMS log : Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: That error suggests that you try to do a SQL Server login using a name that looks like a Windows account - instead of specifying that you want to do an Integrated/Trusted connection. I.e., you don't specify the right login properties. Pls add to your post information about what client you use to connect and how that client is configured regarding connection information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided is not necessarily correct, for these types of errors.

Firstly, your server is attempting to login a NT Service account user to use SSIS. You've either accidentally installed SSIS along with your normal SQL Server instance, or you've failed to provide the user login for that service. Installing SSIS alone, does not create the logins necessary to use SSIS.

The error message

> "Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason:
> Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]"

indicates that the NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150 didn't map an account in SQL Server.

Secondly, open SSMS, connect to this instance, right-click on logins -> New login to add it to SQL Server login.

Based on my test, the default configuration did not add the account to login automatically, but this service requires the access to SQL Server, at least.

You may also get a second error in `EventViewer`:

> Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\SSISScaleOutMaster150'. Reason:
> Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'SSISDB'. [CLIENT:
> ]

That's because SSIS has not been installed properly. Re-install it.

Comment: After creating the SQL server login `NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster150`, I had to restart the system, but then it finally worked!

Comment: "*That's because SSIS has not been installed properly. Re-install it.*" How can we tell what was improperly installed regarding SSIS? What should we do differently when we reinstall it? I have already done the first part of your answer, which is create a login for the SQL account attempting to run the SSIS package, and it has been given rights to connect, read, and write to SSISDB in SSMS, is active and enabled, etc.

Comment: I should have said "most likely"

Answer (score -2):

**Reason**: Windows Administrator Account was **Disabled**!.
[image]

Comment: Was that administrator account the one running SQL Server service?

Comment: That's not the real reason for your original problem